# Numerically robust mechanism to find a basis for the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods, computer-science

Say you are in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and are given a set of directions that is contained in some plane.

The span is, by definition, isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and thus the null basis is given by a single vector pointing in the orthogonal direction to the plane.

Now, say I give you the same set but I perturb one of the vectors a tiny wee bit. Now the span is technically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^3}$ but the coefficients of points that are in the orthogonal direction of the plane are huge.

In this case I would like to pretend that the original set of points is contained in the plane even though it technically isn't.

1. How do I measure how degenerate the input set is? I.e. I want not just the rank but how   close to orthognal the basis vectors are to each other.
2. In the case where the above metric is poor, how can I create a new basis that contains all the original vectors plus some more that make the span be better conditioned?

Comment: In the matter of rank-revealing techniques the SVD is the most commonly used. The singular vectors for the smallest eigenvalue contain the normal vector. // What basis vectors do you want to test for orthogonality in 1.)?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am given an entire bundle of them with arbitrarily many vectors so I would need to figure out how to pick the best basis for that.

Comment: What would "best" be in "best basis"? In a certain sense the SVD also picks that as the first singular vector will point in the main direction of the given bundle, the second orthogonal but in the plane. The name "principal component analysis" describes the same decomposition, but is connected to a more geometric interpretation.